# Two answers with no up-votes,which to choose?

Tags: discussion

I posted a question, I got two answers but not even a single up-vote. Now which answer should I choose as my answer, also there is no comments except the Two volunteers who have answered. I can't delete the question as it has already been answered. Don't know what to do so posted this dilemma.

P.S.-Not satisfied with both the answers.

Comment: Then don't accept an answer. You don't have to accept, it's just there if you want to.

Comment: If neither of the answers have any upvote, then you could delete the question (if you want to).

Comment: @devnull:No i can't delete it although i can flag it.

Comment: @Mr.Pandey, why do you feel you have to accept an answer?

Comment: @gunr2171:I am not saying that i have to accept an answer but how can i find my answer?

Comment: @Mr.Pandey, what do you mean by "find my answer"? You can start a bounty on a question to raise awareness of the question to potentially get more views.

Comment: @gunr2171:Yeah! that's a good idea..I never though about it.Thanks

Comment: @DavidWallace:I haven't accepted any answer yet and you are welcome to answer the question. If I find it satisfactory I will definitely make it as accepted. :)

Comment: No, when I said "I", I didn't mean me.  I meant anyone looking at your question.  Anyway, I have no idea which question  you're talking about (and that's not an invitation to tell me).

Comment: @DavidWallace:Anyway thanks for your comment/advise. Let the question rest in peace. I have already got 3 down-votes here. Seems I have asked something that I shouldn't ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't flag it and don't delete it - that's negative behaviour.

You are not obligated to accept any answer at all, especially if none so far are satisfactory. Leave it be, someone else may answer it in the future. or you could consider expanding the question and including more detail in the hope of attracting a better answer. When you have enough rep you could consider posting a bounty on it to attract attention.

Alternatively you can post your own answer if you've solved your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Then don't accept an answer.

The feature is there so if *you*, the question asker, saw an answer that solved your problem, you could mark it as "accepted", so that the rest of the internet would see quickly that it was "the answer".

But there is absolutely no obligation to do this. Some people might give you a hard time if you *never* accept, but it's your choice on if an when to accept.

I have [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19793377/1043380) that has a good answer, but it's not what I'm looking for, so I won't accept it. I'm just going to wait until someone walks across the question and gives the answer I'm looking for.

You can also start a bounty to raise awareness of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Like @gunr2171 said, just leave it. You should only ever accept an answer if it satisfies your question. That's not to say you should only accept an answer if it's exactly what you were looking for, because the answer won't always be what you expected or wanted. But if it is answered so that you don't have any further questions on that exact topic, you should probably accept something.